# Local Notifications Stopped working on iOS After Adding FCM Support

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I followed the steps for adding [Firebase Messaging library](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase) and I could receive notifications on Android and iOS. I am facing an issue with receiving local notifications on iOS, after adding firebase messaging support App was not receiving local notifications. I am using a different library for handling local notifications: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification. Any help/guidance regarding the same will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you better use the local notification from rnFirebase (invertase), you've added.

It's easy to implement,  works like a charm, and you can get rid of unneeded component (like react-native-push-notification) in your app.

All you need to send a local notification with rnFirebase is: `notifications.displayNotification(notif);` (after you've setup notification-component of rnFirebase: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/android)